# Ajax errors logged twice by ELMAH

Tags: asp.net, error-handling, elmah

I am using ELMAH for error logging and if the error occurs during partial postback (from an event handler of a control wrapped in an update panel), then it is logging the errors twice. I am NOT using the "MsAjaxDeltaErrorLog" module, but instead programmatically logging the errors from "AsyncPostBackError" event handler of ScriptManager control. I am doing this to avoid redirection to generic page for errors occurred during partial postbacks. I turned off redirection in web.config. here is the code that logs the exception

```
    protected void ScriptManager1_AsyncPostBackError(object sender, AsyncPostBackErrorEventArgs e)
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Items["AjaxError"] = "Ajax";
        ErrorSignal.FromCurrentContext().Raise(e.Exception,HttpContext.Current);
    }

    and in Global.asax, I am redirecting manually

protected void ErrorLog_Logged(object sender, ErrorLoggedEventArgs e)
{
  if (!HttpContext.Current.Items.Contains("AjaxError"))
  {
                    var pageName = e.Entry.Error.StatusCode == 404 ? "FileNotFoundPage" : "GenericErrorPage";
                    var redirectPage = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[pageName];
                    Response.Redirect(String.Format("{0}?ExceptionId={1}&ExceptionMessage={2}", redirectPage, Server.UrlEncode(e.Entry.Id),
                                      Server.UrlEncode(e.Entry.Error.Message)));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**From Elmah website:**
[(http://code.google.com/p/elmah/wiki/MSAjax)](http://code.google.com/p/elmah/wiki/MSAjax)

> Potential Issues
>
> Unfortunately, the
> MsAjaxDeltaErrorLogModule is not a
> perfect solution. Due to the way it
> works, there is an extremely small
> possibility that errors will get
> logged twice within ELMAH. For this to
> occur, the following must happen:
>
> 1. The unhandled exception must occur during a Partial PostBack
> 2. It must occur before the OnInit method of
>    System.Web.UI.PageRequestManager is
>    called.
>
> This will mean that both the standard
> ELMAH modules and the
> MsAjaxDeltaErrorModule will capture
> the exception.
>
> In reality, the chances of this
> happening are going to be fairly
> slender. .NET Framework 3.5
>
> An updated version of Microsoft Ajax
> was shipped with version 3.5 of the
> .NET Framework. This new version
> changed the way that unexpected errors
> in Partial PostBacks were handled,
> removing the call to Response.End.
> Therefore, if you continue to use the
> MsAjaxDeltaErrorLogModule with this
> version of the framework, you will see
> all unhandled errors in Partial
> PostBacks being logged twice in ELMAH.*

Im on the same position you are, and everytime I get a asyn error I get the problem logged twiced, but I guess were stuck unless we modify ELMAH's source code